# Alternative to Macromedia flash [Not Flash Player]

Tags: alternative

What is the best flash building alternative for Adobe flash or Macromedia flash ?

Comment: Do you want to make web-embedded Flash video? See [How do I author Adobe Flash movies?](http://askubuntu.com/q/60404) To make animations like with Adobe Flash CS? See [Is there animation software available?](http://askubuntu.com/q/82437) or [What's a good 2D animation program (an alternative for e.g. Flash CS)?](http://askubuntu.com/q/8611) To make *interactive* web-embedded Flash content? It may be hard (except through a Windows/OS  X VM). See [Flash/SWF Editor For Ubuntu 12.10](http://askubuntu.com/q/208434) and [How to install adobe flash professional cs5.5?](http://askubuntu.com/q/289119)

Comment: [How to write Flash Action Scripts in Linux machine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356077/how-to-write-flash-action-scripts-in-linux-machine) (on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)), [suggested by Karthik T](http://askubuntu.com/questions/208434/flash-swf-editor-for-ubuntu-12-10#comment259109_208434), may be a better resource if you need to be able to create interactive, web-embedded Flash content (other than just video).